# android application on market

Tags: android, google-play

In case if I'll unpublish my application from android market(play store) will my application uninstalled from users devices?
Is there any possibility to uninstall my application from devices?

Comment: how many downloads of your app are out there?

Comment: your question is un-clear. Yes it is possible for any user to uninstall an application that they installed from the market.

Comment: I think he wants google to _pull_ the downloads back, aka forcibly delete it from devices that downloaded it. I doubt it.

Comment: You cannot uninstall your application from other peoples' devices.

Comment: ahh, I see. Yup you have no way of forcing it to be uninstalled. It is technically possible for google to do it (They have remote uninstalled some instances of malware) but they don't do it just because you unpublished.

Answer (score 0):

No. If a user has installed your application it is at their discretion to uninstall; even if you have unpublished from the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

Only Google can retroactively remove install applications from devices (in instances of malware apps). This is not something you, as the developer, can do. Even with your own application.

If you unpublish your application, it will not be uninstalled from any devices that already installed it. They won't be able to re-install it from the market either.